How can I upload an image to a Supabase bucket using the REST API?
I would like to use Supabase's own REST API instead of the JavaScript client library (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload) provided by them.
Something like this:
const productImageFile = productData.image.split("\\")[2];
        const sanitizedProductImageFile = productImageFile.replace(
          /[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/g,
          "_"
        );
        const file = new File([productData.image], sanitizedProductImageFile);

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        const productImageBucketApiResponse = await fetch(
          `${import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/object/${import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_BUCKET_NAME}/images`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              apikey: import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_KEY,
            },
            body: formData,
          }
        );


You can do so as the client library is doing exactly that in the background. Just take a look at how this is implemented in the JS library to understand how it can be accomplished.
